# How can I create a for loop to create a list of the p-values I want from a Wilcoxon Test of certain columns of two dataframes in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, testing

I have two dataframes each with the same columns but different values and what I want is to perform a Wilcoxon test and obtain the p-value by comparing a column of a dataframe with the same column of the other dataframe. I attach an example of my data. The first dataframe called dataframe_presential_B2:

| counter_eh | counter_uff | counter_mm | counter_a |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

And another dataframe called dataframe_virtual_B2:

| counter_eh | counter_uff | counter_mm | counter_a |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 |

What I have of code is this:

```
result = stats.wilcoxon(dataframe_presencial_B2['counter_mm'], dataframe_virtual_B2['counter_mm'])
print(result.pvalue)
```

But of course, in my dataframes I have many more columns to analyse so going one by one is very long, and I wanted to know if it is possible to develop a for loop to show me in a list all the p-values for each of the columns I want in my dataframes because not all of them interest me. Following the example I have given, I would only be interested in the columns counter_eh, counter_uff and counter_mm, the one for counter_a would not interest me. So in the for loop should appear these 3.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
from scipy.stats import wilcoxon

df1 = dataframe_presential_B2.melt(value_name='presential')
df2 = dataframe_virtual_B2.melt(value_name='virtual')

df1 = df1.groupby('variable').agg(list)
df2 = df2.groupby('variable').agg(list)
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
pvals = df.drop('counter_a').apply(lambda x: wilcoxon(x.presential, x.virtual).pvalue, axis=1)
print(pvals)
```

Output:

```
variable
counter_eh     0.317311
counter_mm     0.654721
counter_uff    0.179712
dtype: float64
```